# The pullback of a nontrivial line bundle is nontrivial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $E$ a holomorphic vector bundle over $X$ of rank $2$. Let $\mathbb{P}(E)$ denote the projectivization of $E$, with the natural map $p: \mathbb{P}(E) \rightarrow X$. It is apparently true that if $M$ is a nontrivial (holomorphic) line bundle on $X$, then $p^*M$ is a nontrivial (holomorphic) line bundle on $\mathbb{P}(E)$, but I am not sure how to prove it.

The result would be immediate if $p$ had a section, but I don't believe this should be the case in general? I would especially appreciate an answer that is essentially elementary (e.g. no spectral sequences), since this question was asked on an exam for an essentially elementary class, but all answers are welcome.

Comment: By projection formula $p_*(p^*M) = M \otimes p_*O = M$.  So, if $p^*M = O = p^*O$ then $M = O$.

Comment: Thanks, what you wrote makes sense to me from thinking about the algebraic geometry picture, but I have to admit that this is a point I'm fuzzy on - what is going on in the differential geometry picture? In other words, doesn't this correspond geometrically to "pushing forward" the vector bundle $p^*M$ back down to X - why is that allowed in this case?

Comment: Here $p^\ast$ and $p_\ast$ are operations on sheaves (of $\mathcal O$-modules), not on vector bundles. And vector bundles are identified with their locally free sheaves of sections. Note by the way that Sasha's proof uses only one property of the map $p$, namely that $p_\ast \mathcal O \cong \mathcal O$.

Comment: @anon: In your math.SE question you didn't tell us that you take the associated projective bundle. Then of course we have $p_* \mathcal{O} = \mathcal{O}$ and the Leray argument also works. Notice that without projectivization, $p_* \mathcal{O} = \mathrm{Sym}(E)$ would be too large.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I forgot to say that! I'm aware Sasha is working with the sheaf of sections - I'm just confused about a (very basic) point, which is what is going on in the (geometric) vector bundle picture? Is this argument not saying that $p^*M$ pushes back down to $M$ as vector bundles?

Comment: In other words, I just want to convert this argument into one that is phrased purely in terms of traditional vector bundles.

Comment: @anon: vector bundles don't have a notion of pushforward. (You can push forward the corresponding sheaf but this operation won't preserve local freeness in general.)

Comment: I know vector bundles don't push forward in general ... which is why I'm asking for a vector bundle interpretation of what's going on here, where we are ``pushing forward'' a vector bundle along a map, no? Anyway, I think I have figured out what this means in the terms I was looking for: if you have a section on $p^* M$, then it's constant along fibers in $\mathbb{P}(E)$ because it's a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{P}^1$, so you get a section over $X$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

The pullback, $p^*$, is an injective map on integral cohomology.  Thus if $c_1(M)\neq 0$, $c_1(p^*M)=p^*c_1(M)\neq 0$.  Then you just need to show that a complex line bundle is non-trivial if and only if its first Chern class is non-zero.  While that works for $C^\infty$ bundles, I think Pic(X) might give you holomorphically non-trivial line bundles with vanishing first Chern class.